# How should I pass this integer array in to this function?

Tags: c, pointers, parameter-passing

For this assignment, my professor gave us the following function header:

```
void thisFunc(Node** root, const int * elements[], const int count)
```

Presumably, this is correct and I cannot change this.

Const int *elements is an array of int values taken with scanf; I declared mine with

```
int entries[atoi(argv[1])-1];
```

and successfully populated it with

```
   for(int a=0; a < atoi(argv[1]); a++) {
      scanf("%i", &entries[a]);
   }
```

but I'm struggling with calling thisFunc.

```
   thisFunc(&bst, entries, atoi(argv[1]));
```

which throws the obvious error:

```
note: expected 'const int **' but argument is of type 'int *'
```

It's expecting a constant array of pointers to pointers of ints, if I'm right? What should I be doing with my entries array that will make it a valid parameter?

I've tried passing entries in by reference (&entries), but I'm a little lost.

Comment: `const int * elements[]` is not an array of integers. Its an array of pointers to integer..

Comment: @haris Actually, it is not an array at all. It is adjusted to pointer to pointer to int.

Comment: @juanchopalnza only when used as a function parameter. But that's really arguing symantix.

Comment: @aruisdante It is a function parameter. And it is an important distinction.

Comment: @aruisdante Not trying to be rude, but I think you meant "semantics", unless there's an SO inside joke I'm not in on.

Comment: It's obviously just a typo, Dogbert.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The signature implies that you are going to pass a pointer to a pointer, which in turn suggests dynamic allocation (rather than a variable-length array):

```
// Read the length once, and store it for future reference.
// Calling atoi on the same string multiple times is inefficient.
int len = atoi(argv[1]);
int *entries = malloc(sizeof(int) * len);
... // Populate the data in the same way, but use len instead of atoi(argv[1])
...
// Now you can take address of entries
thisFunc(&bst, &entries, len);
...
// Do not forget to free memory allocated with malloc once you are done using it
free(entries);
```

Note: with this said, I am nearly certain that your professor has made a small mistake in declaring `thisFunc`, and that it should have been declared like this:

```
void thisFunc(Node** root, const int elements[], const int count)
```

The reason I think that this should be the correct signature is that there needs to be an intent behind making a variable a pointer, and such intent is clearly missing from making `elements` a `const` pointer-to-pointer. Since `elements` is `const`, the signature tells me that `thisFunc` is not going to modify the data behind `elements`. At the same time, by using a pointer the signature tells me that it is going to modify `elements` itself, which does not look like what the function is going to do, because `elements` are read elsewhere.

Comment: Of course! I should've realized.  I'm new to C and used to Java, so I'm still getting used to the options that come with being able to manage memory.  Thank you very much.  :)

Comment: Right now I'm getting the error "expected 'const int **' but argument is of type 'int **'".  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: This works if the function needs a pointer to a pointer to an array of `int`... but not if it needs an array of pointers to `int`.  The function header could mean either one, but to me the array brackets suggest the latter (for the former I'd expect `const int **elements` rather than `const int *elements[]`).

Comment: @Rohawk I am almost certain that your professor has made a mistake: he put an extra asterisk in front of `elements`. You can make it run with `const` double-pointer using a cast ([demo](http://ideone.com/bznvPN)) but it is useless: you are not supposed to modify entries anyway, and you need an extra dereference inside `myFunction`. Without an extra asterisk it's a lot more natural, and there is no need to cast ([another demo](http://ideone.com/vZNPGF)).

Comment: It seems to work if inside main I create "const int * nums = entries;", call the function with &nums as the second param, then in thisFunc create "const int * test = *elements;" and refer to values as "test[#]".  I have absolutely no doubt that there's a better way to handle this issue, so I'm still extremely open to suggestions.  I'll try the one you just posted, thanks again.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Indeed, the function has a prototype like this: `void thisFunc(Node** root, const int elements[], const int count)`.Someone did asked a [similiar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26395841/1057230) regarding the same set up. Since, I didn't knew, that it is a part of an assignment, I tried to answer that, to explain, that in a best way. But looking at this question again, it seems like, it is actually some college/university assignment

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify the values in array entries[] using your mentioned function then change your call to:
thisfunc(&bst, &entries, atoi(argv[1]));

The problem is you are passing "entries" which is an array but your function is expecting a pointer to int array[]. So pass the adrress of entries which is "&entries".

Answer (score -4):

Have you tried to convert it implicitly?

```
(const int**)variable;
```

done ;)

Comment: i know you cannot comment.. but think and ponder over your answer before posting..

Comment: The mistake? Just try out what happens when you do `return **(const int**)entries;`...